# Front React server crash : node:internal/buffer:959

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, strapi

I am building an ecommerce website using Strapi (back) and React (front).

I don't why i have the current error:

node:internal/buffer:959
super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
at new ArrayBuffer ()
at new Uint8Array ()
at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:959:5)
at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1062:12)
at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (node:buffer:384:10)
at read (C:\Users\lenoa\Documents\ELN WEB\Projets en cours\freedom-x\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:597:32)
at C:\Users\lenoa\Documents\ELN WEB\Projets en cours\freedom-x\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:657:7
at C:\Users\lenoa\Documents\ELN WEB\Projets en cours\freedom-x\frontend\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:362:16
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)

It happens when i am navigate on the website, i don't know why.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to put after the response:

```
 await setTimeout(0)
```

If this doesn't work, check out which Node version do you have. Maybe you need to install the node 64 and rebuild all de node modules.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured it out.
If you have the same issue : just uninstall Nodejs from your computer, then reinstall it.
It work for me.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

### I have this problem when using node js version 18. I switched to 16 and the project started
nvm install 16

nvm use 16.19.1
---------- or
nvm use [your version]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).